# RadWindow doesn't show when using Implicit Style

Tags: wpf, telerik

I'm trying to show a `RadWindow` using implicit style but it seems much more difficult as expected. For simplicity I've also created a sample project here (you've to add Telerik's assemblies in order to run it, you can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1luX5YiF87L2Amij3_L1lbcTN80H5wXy7)

I've defined my `RadWindow` as

```
<telerik:RadWindow x:Class="LightWeightGrid.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LightWeightGrid"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Header="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

<telerik:RadWindow.Style>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadWindow" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadWindowStyle}" />
</telerik:RadWindow.Style>
<Grid>
   <TextBlock Text="Here I'm"></TextBlock>
```

and showing it in the main class as

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 w = new   Window1();
    w.Show();
}
```

But I don't see it... If I turn to Explicit style it works... I've tried the proposal on SO but with no luck,what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to a theme assembly where the implicit styles are defined, for example `Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8.dll`, and then merge the theme resource dictionaries into your application, for example in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml"/>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Windows8;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```